# How to do several concurrent mass inserts without duplicates?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have 4 processes and each of them will be inserting 1000 records with `title, url (unique)` into `blog_posts` table all at the same time. Some of the records will contain a duplicate `url`.

Inserting in a transaction for each process would fail even if I check record existence prior to inserting it due to a race condition between processes. A single mass insert per process would also fail. How do I do this **in a fast way** with Postgres?

I'm thinking of queueing the records from each process into Redis or something and mass inserting them from there in order to prevent race conditions, but I though maybe there is some better way.

Comment: Are you looking a solution for PostgresSQL? Just confirming.

Comment: Yes, I've updated the question.

Comment: See if this helps. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30499/optimal-way-to-ignore-duplicate-inserts

Comment: Or using MERGE/UPSERT: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SQL_MERGE

Comment: Are you doing it from a client that can survive an exception?

Answer (score 1):

I went with upgrading to Postgres v9.5 and using a mass insert with `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` which gave me both the speed and ability to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution that I would suggest - to go with temp tables, 1 for data with duplicates, 2 to filter through it (though it might not work in some scenarios).

It's also a little verbose, but all statements are rather simple, and it's easy to fine-tune it to exactly what you want.

Here is a hypothetical example. In this case I assume that I won't operate on duplicates - I just want uniques (based on URL). I try to comment steps so it's more/less easily visible how to adjust that logic to whichever is required.

Setup temp table and populate it with whichever data.

```
--
-- Create temp table, which will store all data, including duplicates.
--
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS abc_with_dupes;
--

CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS abc_with_dupes (
    url   text NOT NULL,
    title text NOT NULL
);

--
-- Create temp table, that will be closer to desired result, with constraints.
--
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS abc;
--

CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS abc (
    url   text NOT NULL,
    title text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT abc_pkey PRIMARY KEY (url)
);

--
-- Sample Data, into temp
--

INSERT INTO abc_with_dupes (url, title) VALUES
('http://example.com', 'a'),
('http://example.com', 'b'),
('http://example.ca' , 'c'),
('http://example.us' , 'd'),
('http://example.ru' , 'e');
```

Migrate only unique records to abc temp table. Logic will change depends on what needs to be done with duplicates, in this case there are simply ignored.

```
INSERT INTO abc (url, title) (
    SELECT X.url, T.title FROM (
        SELECT
            url
        FROM abc_with_dupes
        GROUP BY url
        HAVING(COUNT(*)) = 1
    ) AS X
    JOIN abc_with_dupes T USING(url)
);
```

And to check results:

```
--
-- Quick check: Records that ended up under abc temp table - unique.
--
-- ('http://example.ca' , 'c')
-- ('http://example.us' , 'd')
-- ('http://example.ru' , 'e')
-- 

SELECT * FROM abc;

--
-- Quick check: Records that have duplicate and didn't make to abc temp table
-- 
-- ('http://example.com', 'a')
-- ('http://example.com', 'b')
--

SELECT T.title, X.url FROM (
    SELECT
        url
    FROM abc_with_dupes
    GROUP BY url
    HAVING(COUNT(*)) > 1
) AS X
JOIN abc_with_dupes T USING(url)
```

Hopefully that will be helpful in some way.